Isabelle/HOL eprover processes do not exit
I'm running Isabelle2024 on Windows 10. When using sledgehammer, some eprover processes do not exit after sledgehammer is completed. Each of these processes can consume gigabytes of memory (which grows even after sledgehammer exits) and stall my system eventually. This only happens when my theory is "complex" enough somehow.
The process tree of such eprover process looks like

Other ATP processes exit correctly, including the eprover called by zipperposition.

I can provide a process log if needed.

I have similar experiences with Isabelle 2024 on Debian/Linux. I had to deactivate e for sledgehammer because it tended to eat up my RAM.

@BenjaminBisping That's interesting because this does not happen to my Ubuntu.. And actually in Isabelle2023 on Windows 10 some other ATPs also do not get cleaned up by sledgehammer. I thought the issue's gone after the update until my current work's complexity grew beyond some extent recently.
